# Sql Merge statement causes duplication while multithreading

Tags: sql, sql-server, multithreading

I have a merge statment that performs an upsert based on a key. (for simplification, we will just call it RefId). This is to ensure that the table is unique by `RefId`.
However, in production we have multiple servers that insert into this table using this stored proc, and if two servers insert using the same RefId at very close intervals, duplication occurs (i.e 2 inserts) instead of 1 insert and update. I believe it is because, SQL server locks the newly inserted row and the other parallel called stored proc is unable to detect it's existence. NoLock is not supported for the MERGE statement so there's no obvious workaround that I can see.
 I have simulated parallel inserts using multiple threads (instead of servers) and ocassionally duplication occurs in this case as well. Other than enforcing a unique constraint on the DB, (which I can't for reasons not in my control) is there any way I can get my upsert to work as expected in concurrent cases?

Here's the stored proc (it works correctly when the insert-updates are made with a reasonable timing difference, just fails in parallel cases)

```
WITH UniqueData AS 
    ( SELECT * FROM 
      ( SELECT *, rank() over ( PARTITION BY RefId ) AS UniqueRank 
          FROM @Data  
      ) AS Ranked WHERE UniqueRank=1 
    )
  MERGE MyTable AS destination
  USING UniqueData AS source
  ON ( destination.RefId = source.RefId)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (RefId, Miles,UpdateUTC)
    VALUES( source.RefId, source.Miles, getutcdate())
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
               destination.Miles = ISNULL(source.Miles , destination.Miles ),
               destination.UpdateUTC = getutcdate()
```

Comment: "and if two servers insert using the same RefId at very close intervals, duplication occurs " - not sure I understand. Why would you NOT expect duplicates in that situation?

Comment: Sounds like you need to set some unique constraint if you want to avoid multiple writes to create the same value. If you want a procedure to be able to handle multi threads, you'll need to make your architecture in that manner. And NOLOCK would seemingly just make your problem worse as you actually want more locking.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I can't add unique constraints in the DB because of some DB policies. @MitchWheat - I just expected that merge would somehow check if there were any pending newly inserted rows, and would reorder insert-updates based on that. As to why...I guess it's more semantically correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use WITH (HOLDLOCK)

```
...
 MERGE MyTable WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS destination
...
```

And you can read the details here: 
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to be the easy fix for this problem.

Comment: Thanks. Just what was needed!